# Output alphabet in two rows using python 3

Tags: python-3.x

My code below is correct kind of but I just need to make the 2nd for loop tab into the next line. This prints out the entire alphabet in lower case. I had initially tried the escape sequences but that just made my output weird.

```py
def main():
    for i in range(65, 78):
        print(chr(i), end='')
    for x in range(78, 91):
        print(chr(x), end='')
main()
```

Comment: i have edited your question such that the text is code format. It helps users replicate and therefore answer questions more efficiently...  please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the two for loops on the same indentation level and add a print to introduce a new line:

```
def main():
    for i in range(65, 78):
        print(chr(i), end='')
    print('')
    for x in range(78, 91):
        print(chr(x), end='')

main()
```

Comment: Thank you for that. Still new to me.

Comment: Welcome. It if helped can you please set it as accepted answer? Thank you!